# a nondifferentiable convex program!

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need to solve the following problem:

\begin{equation} 
\min_{(y, a)\in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R}\quad \ 
a+\beta\sum_{j=1}^m\max(0,y^Tb_j-a)+\|x-y\|_2^2
\end{equation}

My efforts show that $y^* =-0.5 \beta\sum_{j=1}^mb_j\delta_j+x$, where $\delta_j\in [0,1]$ for all $j\in [m]$, but I am not sure how to compute $a^*$ and even $\delta_j$'s. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The choice of $\beta$ has a significant impact on the program.

Comment: Even if we can convert it to a feasibility problem that only has linear constraints would be nice I think. I have a guess this is possible, what do you think? @copper.hat

Comment: Thank you for this note, which analysis exactly? I think you mean for $\beta<0$ it is not convex, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant $<0$ for non convex.

Comment: I just do not see how your method can be generalized to the case of $\beta\in (0,1)$ because $\beta$ cannot be removed in this scenario as well.

Comment: Some of my comments above are incorrect and I will remove them.

Comment: So, you mean we have: $\max(a,\beta y^Tb_j+a(1-\beta))\ge \beta y^Tb_j+a(1-\beta)\ge \beta y^Tb_j$ for each $j\in [m]$ if $a$ is small enough, right? Then basically, use the same argument and find $y^*$ and next give the range of $a^*$.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments which are mostly deleted, The problem has a solution **iff** $\beta \ge 1$. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\beta \le 0$ then the cost can be written as
$c(y,a) = a-|\beta| \sum_k \max(0, b_k^Ty -a) + \|y-x\|_2^2 \le a + \|y-x\|_2^2 $, and so the program is unbounded below and has no solution.

If $\beta > 0$, the cost can be written as
$c(y,a) = \sum_k \max(a, \beta b_k^T y+ {(1-\beta) \over q} a) + \|y-x\|_2^2$.

If $\beta \in (0,1)$, then
$\inf c(y,a) \le c(0,a) = \sum_k \max(a, {(1-\beta) \over q} a) + \|x\|^2_2$ and we see that the right hand side is unbounded below and so the program has no solution.

If $\beta = 1$, the cost is $c(y,a) = \sum_k \max(a, b_k^T y) + \|y-x\|_2^2$, and it is clear that
$c(y,a) \ge  \sum_k b_k^T y + \|y-x\|_2^2$. Since for any $y$ we can choose $a$ such that we have equality, we can just focus on minimising $f(y) = \sum_k b_k^T y + \|y-x\|_2^2$.
This is a convex problem and setting the gradient to zero gives
$y^*=x-{1 \over 2} \sum_k b_k$. You can choose any $a^* \le \min_k b_k^T y^*$.

If $\beta >1$ then some work is needed to show that a solution exists, but it does not appear to have a simple solution as in the $\beta=1$ case.
The problem can then be written as a semidefinite QP:
$\min_{(y,a,t)} \{a + \beta \sum_j t_j +\|y-x\|_2^2  \mid 0 \le t_j, b_j^T y -a \le t_j \}$

Comment: Thank you for this interesting method. When I posted this question, I tried to simplify it and it seems that your method is taking a nice advantage of that. Basically, there is a coefficient before the sum, which is not necessarily one! Do you mind if I edit the question to that scenario? I do not see that your method can be generalized to the new problem or not!

Comment: Go ahead, may take a while for me to update.

Comment: Done! thank you again!

Comment: Thank you; this is very helpful. Indeed, the most interesting case for me is when $\beta\in (0,1)$, which I did not expect to be unbounded! To remove this issue, in my algorithm, I can add one constraint to $y$, say, $1^Ty=1$, do you think this helps to bound the problem? Or I can have $L\le y\le U$ for some $L$ and $U$, or in the worst scenario both of them together!

Comment: The unboundedness is coming from the $a$, the $y$ is fine because of the $\|y-x\|^2$ term.

Comment: This is quite interesting and the same confusing because this problem comes from CVaR basically: https://www.ise.ufl.edu/uryasev/files/2011/11/CVaR1_JOR.pdf; see (17) in this paper. But it seems that everyone agrees that CVaR always has a solution but I think your reasoning can be applied to the CVaR problem as well. So, not sure what I am missing here! I really appreciate your comment.

Comment: What I am trying to say is basically when you look at Table 6 in their paper, you would see the coefficient for the sum term is less than one, but yet their optimal value is positive. But your analysis can be applied to their problem and they should get -infinity but they do not!

Comment: I do not really have time to read the paper in detail, but there are differences in the formulation, for example your $\beta$ above is ${1 \over q (1 -\beta)}$ in the paper. There may be some other considerations that are in play here, but would need some reading to discover. (Rockafellar is a heavyweight in terms of convex optimisation.)

Comment: Thank you for your time, really appreciate it! In their paper, $\beta\in (0,1)$ and $q\in \mathbb N$, so for large $q$'s, they always have: $q(1-\beta)>1$. This is the case, your analysis shows the problem is unbounded! Anyways, when you look at Table 6, you do see there are cases where $1/q(1-\beta)<1$ but there is a finite optimal value!

Comment: I posted a complementary question related to this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799520/c-var-approximation-problem.
I would really appreciate it if you take a look. @copper.hat