# C-VaR approximation problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, upper-lower-bounds, non-convex-optimization

In the paper written by Rockafellar about C-VaR (https://www.ise.ufl.edu/uryasev/files/2011/11/CVaR1_JOR.pdf), it is explained that this quantity can be approximated using the following problem (problem 17 in their paper):

\begin{equation} 
\min_{(x, \alpha)\in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R}\quad \ 
c(x,\alpha):=\alpha+\frac{1}{q(1-\beta)}
\sum_{k=1}^q(-x^Ty_k-\alpha)^+,
\end{equation}
where $\beta\in (0,1)$ and $q\in \mathbb N$. I am wondering if the solution set of this problem is bounded or not; especially if $\alpha^*$ is bounded or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the paper has the additional constraint that $x \ge 0$ and $\sum_k x_k = 1$, so the set of $x$ values is compact.

Since $\beta \in (0,1)$ we have $1-\beta \in (0,1)$ and so ${1 \over 1-\beta} > 1$ and so $1-{1 \over 1-\beta} < 0$.

\begin{eqnarray}
c(\alpha, x) &=& \alpha + {1 \over q(1-\beta)} \sum_k \max(0, -x^T y_k-\alpha) \\
&=& \alpha + \sum_k \max(0, -{1 \over q(1-\beta)} x^T y_k-{1 \over q(1-\beta)} \alpha) \\
&=& \sum_k \max({\alpha \over q}, -{1 \over q(1-\beta)} x^T y_k + {1 \over q}(1-{1 \over 1-\beta}) \alpha) \\
\end{eqnarray}

As an aside, note that if $\gamma>0$ then $\max(t, u-\gamma t) \ge {u \over 1 + \gamma}$ and so it follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
c(\alpha,x) &\ge& \sum_k {1 \over {1 \over q} ( { \beta \over 1-\beta })} (-{1 \over q(1-\beta)} y_k^T x ) \\
&=& -{ 1\over \beta} (\sum_k y_k)^T x
\end{eqnarray}
Since $x$ is in a compact set it follows that the right hand side is bounded below.

Comment: Fantastic job! So, the objective function as a whole is bounded, since I am more interested in finding an interval for $\alpha^*$, can use what you proved and show that as well that $\alpha^*$ is also bounded below and above?

Comment: No, the objective is not bounded unless you restrict $x$ to lie on a compact set. The above is an LP that is bounded below, so yes $\alpha^*$  is bounded.

Comment: Yes, I meant with that compact constraint you mentioned. Together with that constraint, I meant I was hoping to find an interval for $\alpha^*$ explicitly.

Comment: I imagine that if that were possible that Tyrell would have done so in the paper?

Comment: I guess he wasn't interested in that :)

Comment: I wonder if the KKT conditions based on the subdifferential can give something about bounds of  $\alpha^*$ or not. I mean (26) in the paper!

Comment: I think (but this is just a guess) that such an approach suffers from a chicken & egg problem. Some LPs can be solved explicitly, but given the additional complication of $x \in X$, I suspect little real progress could be made. Again, while this is obviously far from conclusive, if Rockafellar does not see an immediately computable solution there, it would discourage me from spending much time looking. It depends on the value to you in obtaining such a bound, since numerically it is trivial.